# Checking for signed overflow by default, but with opt-out

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

When using clang and/or gcc, is there a way that I can ask the compiler to performed signed integer overflow checking by default (and, for example, abort if it is detected) - but at the same time *opt out* of this check for specific variables or operations?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you [KINT](https://www.usenix.org/conference/osdi12/technical-sessions/presentation/wang). Example:()
[image]

Dynamic check:

Use `clang++` to compile and link your program with `-fsanitize=undefined` flag. Make sure to use `clang++` (not `ld`) as a linker, so that your executable is linked with proper UBSan runtime libraries. You can use `clang` instead of `clang++` if you’re compiling/linking C code.

```
% cat test.cc
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int k = 0x7fffffff;
  k += argc;
  return 0;
}
% clang++ -fsanitize=undefined test.cc
% ./a.out
test.cc:3:5: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'
```

Define the desired behaviour for each kind of check:

- `fsanitize=...`: print a verbose error report and continue execution (default);
- `fno-sanitize-recover=...`: print a verbose error report and exit the program;
- `fsanitize-trap=...`: execute a trap instruction (doesn’t require UBSan run-time support).

For detailed information:

- [Clang 7 documentation UNDEFINEDBEHAVIORSANITIZER](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#availablle-checks)
- [Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC): Instrumentation Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like an interesting tool. It relies on static analysis, which is awesome when it works (and this framework seems to increase that chance) - but in my case I'm actually asking for a dynamic check of all integer math (e.g., something like `add rax, rbx; jo overflow_handler` will be emitted for a signed addition) with the ability to opt-out only for "hot path" checks.

Comment: @BeeOnRope, added dynamic check Signed integer overflow